# Power Shellでtry-catchを使用するとエラー

Tags: windows, powershell

PowerShell3.0でtry-catchを含むスクリプトを実行するとエラーが発生します。Windows7では問題なく実行できました。
以下、実行環境情報です。

・実行マシン

```
Windows Server 2008 R2
```

・PSバージョン
    PS C:\ZabbixPowerShellScript> $PSVersionTable

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
```

・スクリプト

```
Write-Host
Write-Host 'Hello World!'
Write-Host "Good-bye World! `n"
try{}catch[Exception]{}
```

・結果

```
PS C:\ZabbixPowerShellScript> .\test.ps1
At C:\ZabbixPowerShellScript\test.ps1:6 char:2
+ }
+  ~
The Try statement is missing its Catch or Finally block.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingCatchOrFinally
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`catch` と `[Exception]` の間にはスペースが必要です。

```
try {} catch [Exception] {}
```

シンタックスエラーの類ですが、Powershell ISE を利用するとこの手の間違いを指摘してくれるので便利です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]